# Cannot seem to install VMware vCSA 6.7 cert on macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, vmware, certificate

Trying to install the web certificate for my vCenter Server Appliance (vCSA 6.7) on my Mac Mini (running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6). I download the cert.0 file, change the extension to .crt and double-click the file, Keychain Access opens...but then nothing. The cert does not get installed. This is exactly how I've always installed the cert on machines before. Where could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. I [followed the instructions here](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206058318-How-to-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-on-Mac-OSX-) (which was already getting done by the OS), but had to just manually "trust" the CA.